# core.js:30235 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ivy

When i execute the `ng s --open` command, I am getting the browser console error. but there is no errors in the node terminal

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
> at registerNgModuleType (core.js:30235)
> at core.js:30253
> at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
> at registerNgModuleType (core.js:30249)
> at core.js:30253
> at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
> at registerNgModuleType (core.js:30249)
> at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:30387)
> at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:34669)
> at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:34966)
> ```

But there are no errors when I build the application with `ng build --prod`
what could be the reason for the error , as the same code is executing my other machine [image: Error Screen shot]

appplication is also not maiking any API calls

[image: network screen shot]

this is where i am getting error in the core.js
[image: core.js error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

u can delete the node_modules folder and you can do `npm install`, everything works perfectly

Comment: This works, but what is the reason ?

Answer (score 2):

The same problem with me.

Solution:

1. delete the project
2. clone project from your repo
3. npm install
4. open vscode and `select > setting > Online services setting > settings sync > Edit` in `settings.json` and change `"angular.experimental-ivy": true` to `"angular.experimental-ivy": false`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

I tried to delete node_module and  do `npm install` but it is not fixed.

Then, I finally  remove `@angular/material` from `package.json` and reinstalled using `npm install`. It is solved.